# Removing data with a non-numeric column value in R

Tags: r

So I have a dataset that includes the lung capacity of certain individuals. I am trying to analyze the data distributions and relations. The only problem is that the data is somewhat incomplete. Some of the rows include "N/A" as the lung capacity. This is causing an issue because it is resulting in a mean and sd of always "N/A" for the different subsets. How would I form this into a subset so that it only includes the data that isn't N/A?

I've tried this:

```
fData1 = read.table("lung.txt",header=TRUE)
fData2= fData1[fData1$fev!="N/A"]
```

but this gives me an "undefinied columns selected error".

How can I make it so that I have a data set that excludes the rows with "N/A"?

Here is the begining of my data set:

```
 id age    fev height male smoke 
  1  72 1.2840   66.5    1     1
  2  81 2.5530   67.0    0     0
  3  90 2.3830   67.0    1     0
  4  72 2.6990   71.5    1     0
  5  70 2.0310   62.5    0     0
  6  72 2.4100   67.5    1     0
  7  75 3.5860   69.0    1     0
  8  75 2.9580   67.0    1     0
  9  67 1.9160   62.5    0     0
 10  70     NA   66.0    0     1
```

Comment: FWIW `mean` and `sd` both have an `na.rm` argument.

Comment: You need a comma for that line to run without error. `fData1[fData1$fev!="N/A", ]` but I am confused as to why you think `NA` is the same as `"N/A"`

Comment: Instead of `!=NA` I'd rather use `!is.na()`. But I suspect that the answer by @Psidom should solve your problem.

Comment: `na.omit(fData1)` would also work nicely.

Comment: @RichardScriven Definitely ;-)

Comment: @RichardScriven Sorry about that. typo

Comment: Thanks for the different methods! didn't realize there were so many options. Sorry I'm new to R, and a quick google with the documentation wasn't as straight forward as I thought it'd be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to filter out rows with `NA` values, you can use `complete.cases()`:

```
> df
   id age   fev height male smoke
1   1  72 1.284   66.5    1     1
2   2  81 2.553   67.0    0     0
3   3  90 2.383   67.0    1     0
4   4  72 2.699   71.5    1     0
5   5  70 2.031   62.5    0     0
6   6  72 2.410   67.5    1     0
7   7  75 3.586   69.0    1     0
8   8  75 2.958   67.0    1     0
9   9  67 1.916   62.5    0     0
10 10  70    NA   66.0    0     1
> df[complete.cases(df), ]
  id age   fev height male smoke
1  1  72 1.284   66.5    1     1
2  2  81 2.553   67.0    0     0
3  3  90 2.383   67.0    1     0
4  4  72 2.699   71.5    1     0
5  5  70 2.031   62.5    0     0
6  6  72 2.410   67.5    1     0
7  7  75 3.586   69.0    1     0
8  8  75 2.958   67.0    1     0
9  9  67 1.916   62.5    0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to apply the operations excluding the NA values:

```
dat <- read.table("lung.txt", header = T, na.strings = "NA")
mean(dat$fev, na.rm=T) # mean of fev col
sd(dat$fev, na.rm=T)
```

If you simply want to get rid of the NAs:

```
fData1 <- na.omit(fData1)
fData1 <- na.exclude(fData1) # same result
```

If you'd like to save the rows with NA's here are 2 options:

```
fData2 <- fData1[is.na(fData1$fev), ]
fData2 <- subset(fData1, is.na(fData1$fev))
```